# Error en la creacion de la tabla sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

A la hora de crear una tabla con `primary` y `foreign keys` genera varios errores:

```
CREATE TABLE PERSONAL(
    COD_CENTRO NUMBER(4,0) FOREIGN_KEY NOT NULL REFERENCES CENTROS,
    DNI NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    APELLIDOS VARCHAR2(30),
    FUNCION VARCHAR2(15),
    SALARIO NUMBER(10,0));
```

Aqui el error:

> Uncaught Error: near "FOREIGN_KEY": syntax error

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primero definimos la tabla, luego las referencias externas indicando campo de esta tabla y tabla (campo) de la tabla externa ([Documentación](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-create-table/)).

```
CREATE TABLE PERSONAL(
  COD_CENTRO NUMBER(4,0) NOT NULL,
  DNI NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  APELLIDOS VARCHAR2(30),
  FUNCION VARCHAR2(15),
  SALARIO NUMBER(10,0),
  FOREIGN_KEY (COD_CENTRO) REFERENCES CENTROS (COD_CENTRO)
);
```

Comment: Gracias, solo que al final deberia de ser:
FOREIGN KEY (COD_CENTRO) REFERENCES CENTROS (COD_CENTRO)